# Why didn't Psi Corps repeat their experimental efforts to create another Jason Ironheart who is arguably as powerful as a Vorlon?

Tags: babylon-5

The Psi Corps successfully created a being as powerful as a Vorlon in Jason Ironheart. While the research staff who successfully did it was killed, it should not be too difficult to re-create what was successfully created before. If it has been done before, it should not be difficult to do it again. If it has been done before, it means the present state of technology is not too far off.

Why didn't Psi Corps do it again, given that success would mean the human race would make a huge leap in technological power that can help them beat the Minbari and match even the Vorlons and Shadows?

Comment: Given that it worked so well the first time...?

Comment: @Jon Clements, Jason became a "Vorlon", didn't he? That's a resounding success.

Comment: So something so advanced and powerful you can't control it that is beyond need for physical form and probably thinks you're absolutely primitive and not worthy of the time of day... What use is that?

Comment: @Jon Clements, you're right. A technology that cannot be controlled safely by humans is worse than not having it. It's like inventing a nuclear bomb that detonate by itself uncontrollably.

Comment: Also, who is to say that they didn't? It might have been an isolated incident that it worked, Jason could have been slightly more advanced in a specific way that made their drugs work on him in that manner. We also don't know how long their experiment went on for, it could have lasted for years, and the series wrapped up before they concluded the second attempt.

Comment: Who's to say they didn't keep trying, and just haven't managed to hit the exact combination of drugs and surgery that almost worked?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Jason Ironheart was an accident.**

The goal of the Psi Corps project that produced him was not to create a Vorlon-like creature. The goal was to create a telekinetic assassin, one that was stable and had enough fine control to kill an individual by pinching their carotid shut.

Any success or continuation of such a project would have to be speculation, because not a one of them would ever admit such a weapon was in development.

Not to mention, the only eyewitness to this supposed "success" case was Bester. All the black labs folks thought they succeeded in was they created a more effective crazy person.

Answer (score -1):

Given that this is a government project, it's likely that a decision on whether to try again got caught up in committee proceedings, among a lot of blame-shifting.  Even the Psi Corps seems to have been apt to be caught up in typical internal political shenanigans.

Comment: Nonsense, they're merely reexamining the issue to determine efficiencies and efficacies, strengths and weaknesses and determining appropriate policy to carry us into the future, with the usual caveats, in the fullness of time. Source: I've been a scientist in government labs.

Comment: When governments pull crap like assassin programs, they typically *don't* let the committee's know or interfere, because "getting things done" without oversight is usually the whole point.